# How can my site url to be example.com and not example.com/wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

The installation of wordpress is in `example.com/wordpress`. Is there a way moving it to `example.com`?

I don't mean to create a redirect from mydomain.com to `example.com/wordpress` as the word wordpress will still be visible in the url after it gets redirected.

I'd like the site to be accessed under mydomain.com and all the internal links then show `example.com` not `example.com/wordpress/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you log in to your server with FTP? Or maybe you have some server admin panel with files manager?

**Backup your database** and try that:

First, you have to move files from wordpress folder, to parent folder.

Next thing: you have to log in to your database admin (phpMyAdmin) and in wp-options table change first two records (siteurl and home) from `mydomain.com/wordpress` to `mydomain.com`

Last thing: log in to your wordpress panel, install for example "better search replace" plugin, go to plugin page (Tools > better search replace) and search for `mydomain.com/wordpress`. Change it to mydomain.com. Select all tables from database and be sure to **uncheck** the `If checked, no changes will be made to the database, allowing you to check the results beforehand` checkbox.

Run Search/Replace

And it should be fine.